# Why List#indexOf return -1 when no element matching...?

Tags: java, list, data-structures, programming-languages, indexof

Recently, I'm reading the source code of Java Collections Framework and noticed the List#indexOf method.

In the Javadoc of this method, it said "`Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.`"

I'm curious why it should return -1 precisely... Just returning a negative number is enough to meet the requirements, here are my points of view:

1. Compare whether a number is negative is easier than comparing whether a number is -1.
   (Determine whether a number is negative can only compare the sign bit)
2. If allow returning negative values for "no element found", it might be useful for the optimization of some special data structures.

I have searched on Google and SO, but seems no one has the same confusion as me...
Thanks for any answer : ), I'm a noob of Java & SO...

Comment: "*Compare whether a number is negative is easier than comparing whether a number is -1*" Nothing is preventing your calling code from doing exactly that, if you want to.

Comment: a) It has to return some value that can't otherwise be valid; b) it's less error-prone if it returns a specific otherwise-invalid value than "any" (`Comparator`/`Comparable`, I'm looking at you). Why *shouldn't* it return -1?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are confused about or what alternative you want to `-1`?

Comment: Signed integer `-1` is binary beautiful consisting of `1` bits only, right? I don't think this question is worth downvoting, but it's probably a candidate to ask at Retrocomputing S.E..

Comment: With 2. you mean to give the negative value more meaning by allowing the full range of negative values? Do you have a specific data-structure in mind where this would help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Compare whether a number is negative is easier than comparing whether a number is -1

You're thinking about it from the wrong 'side'. Consider Postel's Law:

> Be liberal in what you accept, and conservative in what you send.

And apply it to API design.

You're free to write:

```
if (list.indexOf(something) < 0) ....
```

Which works, **every time**, because `-1` is a negative number.

What possible point is there in writing the API to be 'any negative number' instead?

Let's go through it:

1. It documentarily suggests that users of the API ought to write  `< 0` instead of  `!= -1` - but this is not much of an argument: At best you can then say that the docs can say that whilst -1 is always returned, users of the API ought to use  `< 0` to check. Except this is ridiculous: The proper way to check is **not to call `indexOf` at all** and to call `.contains()` instead.
2. It makes it easier to write code that calls `.indexOf`. **This is false** - you can write  `< 0` just the same. In places where you need the index to be stable, which can occur (imagine you are storing some data in a `java.util.Map<Integer, X>` collection, and your procedure is to look up some key in a list to figure out the id (an integer), and then map that, and you have the need to map 'key not found' to something too. If `.indexOf()` was specced to return any negative number to indicate not found, you'd have to 'clean' this data to -1, but you don't have to, it's guaranteed to be -1.
3. It makes it easier to write implementations of `java.util.List`. This seems like a frivolous argument (how often are you implement j.u.List? Not exactly a daily occurrence, unlike calling it). I rather doubt it'll actually result in shorter code, and I *really* doubt that code would be more readable.

So, what possible point is there?

Remember, it's an API spec. Not every decision needs an explanation beyond 'we needed something specific, as the purpose of an API is to decree the common ruleset. Sometimes just picking anything is the main win, and it doesn't much matter which of many identical choices is picked. As long as everybody is in agreement to use the same pick, it's fine'. That explains why it is -1 and not, say, -100, or `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (-2^31). They could have picked that. They didn't. -1 is marginally simpler (writing `-1` is simpler than Integer.MIN_VALUE, it is the 'first' negative value, and it somewhat matched established convention such as e.g. various C libraries that return -1 to indicate not found.

Answer (score 4):

The method has to return some value that can't otherwise be valid. Optionals didn't exist at the time these APIs were written, so it has to be something within the space of valid `int` values.

A negative value can never otherwise occur, so the value has to be negative.

It's less error-prone if it returns a specific otherwise-invalid value than "any" (`Comparator`/`Comparable`, I'm looking at you).

But why -1 specifically? Almost certainly because they are copying the behavior of `String.indexOf`, which copies the behavior of [`string::find`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) in C++, which returns `string::npos` if not found, [whose value is -1](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/).

At the time Java was designed, several accommodations were made in the language to make it "more familiar" to C++ programmers, to encourage them to give it a try; small things like this mean you don't have to go to the effort of learning entirely different semantics.

Why did the C++ designers choose that value though? ... This could go on for a while. Ultimately, they needed *a* value, and they chose an acceptable one.

Programmers should strive for laziness: given the choice between making up new conventions and going with something that already exists, the latter is often a better choice unless there is a *really* good reason not to.